# Probleme to ave auto excel on pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save

I have small worries with the site of recording of my Excel file in pdf.

I want that the recorded file will be recorded on a file compared to the value of a cell which represents a percentage. Example: The I2 cell = 5% Thus my file will be named Document 5% and I want that it will be recorded in the file Roasts 5%. Except that I find it recorded elsewhere.

Thanks for help

```
Sub Bouton_PDF()

Dim NomFichier As String
Dim Chemin As String

Select Case Range("I2").Text
    Case Is = "1%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE" & Range("I2").Text
    Case Is = "2%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 2%"
    Case Is = "3%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 3%"
    Case Is = "4%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 4%"
    Case Is = "5%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 5%"
   Case Is = "6%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 6%"
   Case Is = "7%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 7%"
   Case Is = "8%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 8%"
   Case Is = "9%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 9%"
   Case Is = "10%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 10%"
   Case Is = "11%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 11%"
   Case Is = "12%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 12%"
  Case Is = "13%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 13%"
  Case Is = "14%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 14%"
  Case Is = "15%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 15%"
  Case Is = "16%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 16%"
  Case Is = "17%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 17%"
  Case Is = "18%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 18%"
  Case Is = "19%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 19%"
   Case Is = "20%"
        Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 20%"
End Select



NomFichier = "GRILLE_TARIFIAIRE_RETAIL_ATLAS_NEGOCE_REMISE_" & Range("I2").Text


            Range("A1:H81").Select
            Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NomFichier, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is "elsewhere"? Because this will give you a clue as to what is happening (as opposed to what you think should happen). You don't use `Chemin`. And you can simplify it to `"Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE" & Range("I2").Text`, but perhaps the text requires specific formatting to get the "%" element into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NomFichier, _
```

you only say what the filename of the PDF should be -- but not the folder where you want to save the PDF. So maybe the PDF, by default, is saved to the folder where the workbook is saved or some other folder.

Also, I think some file systems limit filenames (and file paths) to a certain character limit. If your file path or filename is too long, you may get an error and the PDF may not save.

Try the code below although you may need to change the values of `Chemin` and `NomFichier` (as it wasn't clear to me what you wanted to achieve).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Bouton_PDF()

    Dim percentageValue As String
    percentageValue = Range("I2").Text ' This will refer to cell I2 of whatever sheet is active whilst the code is running.

    Dim Chemin As String ' This is the folder that your PDF will be saved in.
    Chemin = "Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE " & percentageValue & "\"

    Dim NomFichier As String ' This is the name of the PDF.
    NomFichier = "GRILLE_TARIFIAIRE_RETAIL_ATLAS_NEGOCE_REMISE_" & percentageValue & ".pdf"

    ' Say the percentage is 2%:
    ' Then Chemin will be Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 2%\
    ' And NomFichier will be GRILLE_TARIFIAIRE_RETAIL_ATLAS_NEGOCE_REMISE_2%.pdf
    ' And the full file path will be Y:\Sebiha\GRILLE TARIFAIRE\GRILLE TARIFAIRE 1%\GRILLE_TARIFIAIRE_RETAIL_ATLAS_NEGOCE_REMISE_2%.pdf

    ' Again, this will refer to cells A1:H81 of whatever sheet is active whilst the code is running. Include the worksheet's name if you can.
    Range("A1:H81").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Chemin & NomFichier, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: What if the folder does not exist, or if the value in cell `I2` is 25% or 15,7%? Be aware that OP is using a `Select Case` (with a missing `Case Else`) maybe not just to select the folder but could also be to validate `I2` value.

Comment: @EEM To me, `if Len(dir(chemin, vbdirectory)) > 0 then` seems a better way to check for the folder's existence. If it's still necessary to validate the percentage, it can be type coerced into a number, compared with numerical comparison operators (`>`, `<`) in conjunction with checking if `value mod 1 = 0` to only allow whole numbers between a certain range. Seems a better, shorter alternative to 20 mostly repetitive case statements. Just my opinion.

Comment: You should then add that to your answer. But why “to allow only whole numbers”, when validating a percentage?

Comment: @EEM When I said type coerced, I meant parsing the string `"5%"` to turn it into `5` (rather than `0.05`) and `"5.6%"` into `5.6` -- since I think we are only interested in that portion of the string. But yes, I will amend my answer later when I'm not on mobile.